# How to check whether turbo boost is active or not - windows server 2012

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, windows-server, turbo-boost

CPU is : 2x Intel E5 2620 V1

Motherboard is supermicro x9drd

Comment: well i never see it passes 2 GHZ, any chance i can make it permanently 2.5GHZ? i really need boost @TechieGossip

Answer (score 2):

Turbo Boost is on by default.  It can be disabled in the Power Options.  The name is a little misleading - it's more like "allow the processor to temporarily go slightly higher than the rated speed when needed, if temperature limits allow".  Modern Turbo Boost allows the same effect, for individual parts of the chip, so that different parts of the chip are operating at different speeds.  The overall effect is to moderate temperatures and power usage.  It doesn't let you set it "permanently" to the higher speed, because that would be too hot.

Comment: Some BIOS settings let you disable Turbo Boost as well.  Again, this is "disable" so that it's always operating at the lower speed.

Answer (score 0):

It will be active all the time. It is enabled by default.

Turbo Boost Technology dynamically increases the processor's frequency as needed by taking advantage of thermal and power headroom to give you a burst of speed when you need it, and increased energy efficiency when you don’t.

There any plan to disable it? I think you can find in some bios. It depends not sure

If you are looking at the speed in task manager, there's your problem. That is not reliable.

Use [CPUZ](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B4zRvOw8HzDuN1hoQVA1TEFPZFU). Turbo speed also depends on how many cores are being used, For example you have 2.0GHZ as stock speed. You have 6 Cores

> 2.0 GHz (6 cores)
>
> 2.1 GHz (5 cores)
>
> 2.2 GHz (4 cores)
>
> 2.3 GHz (3 cores)
>
> 2.4 GHz (1 or 2 cores)

Actually all Servers/desktops will run turbo all the time if needed since you do not run into power or heat issues on System.

Please Cross check with CPUZ Software.

Comment: any chance to make it permanent?

Comment: check the answer column

Answer (score 0):

The Coffee Lake processors shift to Turbo Mode very, very frequently--even when Windows is idle.  I wager this is true for all Turbo Mode capable processors.  You need a tool that will report your clock speed, like Argus Monitor.  You are in Turbo Mode anytime you see the clock pushed beyond the advertised speed.  If you see no boost while idle, use CPU-Z to either benchmark or stress the CPU while you monitor the clock with another application.

The CPUID commands communicates the CPU capabilities as part of the CPU signature.  Your BIOS likely (but not always) will allow you to enable or disable the Turbo Mode.  Similarly, the OEM can configure the platform to suppress Turbo Mode.  The OEM shapes how Turbo Mode behaves--when it launches, how fast it runs, when it aborts.  That also may (or may not) be exposed through BIOS settings.  If your platform designer suppresses Turbo Mode or if you disable it through BIOS, some packages may still report the CPU as "Turbo Mode=YES!" but that is a sign the software looked at the CPUID and is reporting capabilities, not if it is enabled or engaged.